# Copy and insert to same table no duplication and with minor changes to value

Tags: mysql

**table1:**

```
| user | name |
|------|------|
| 1103 | rack |
| 1102 | tabs |
| 1103 |  aki |
```

I want to copy the record from `table1` back to `table1` again with some minor changes. I only want to copy those users that has a value of `1103` and change its value to `1104` and copy it again to `table1` and if I edit `1103` info, for example- if I edit the `rack` in `1103` I don't want it to change the value that I have copied recently. Below is the correct format that I want -

**table1:**

```
| user |        name |
|------|-------------|
| 1103 | rack-edited |
| 1102 |        tabs |
| 1103 |         aki |
| 1104 |        rack |
| 1104 |         aki |
```

Comment: please provide what you have tried or at least mysql schema to build the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that in 2 statements; copy first, then edit. Or rather, SELECT the rows you want to copy and then INSERT them followed by an UPDATE.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name)
SELECT id + 1, name
FROM table1
WHERE id = 1103;

UPDATE table1
SET name = CONCAT (name, '-edited')
WHERE id = 1103 AND name = 'rack'
```

I'm not 100% sure what your column  names are so I used generic names. `id` is the column with the `1103` and `1104`.

Answer (score 1):

We can insert a copy of rows with some alterations with something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO table1 
 ( `user`
 , `name`
 )
 SELECT 1104       AS `user`
      , t.name     AS `name`
   FROM `table1` t
  WHERE t.user = 1103
```

Answer (score 1):

To copy data alongside changing values, use:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (user, name)
SELECT user+1, name FROM table1
WHERE user = 1103;
```

Here's the sql fiddle before executing above statement: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6647e/1

And sql fiddle after executing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e7f78/2

The output is:

```
| user | name |
|------|------|
| 1103 | rack |
| 1102 | tabs |
| 1103 |  aki |
| 1104 | rack |
| 1104 |  aki |
```

Now, you can play with your previous entries (`1103`) as you want as those will not affect the newly created values(`1104`). For example, you can use:

```
UPDATE table1 SET name = 'rack-edited' WHERE user = 1103 and name = 'rack';
```

Here's the sql fiddle after updating: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1813c/1

And output is:

```
| user |        name |
|------|-------------|
| 1103 | rack-edited |
| 1102 |        tabs |
| 1103 |         aki |
| 1104 |        rack |
| 1104 |         aki |
```